# Storing a content in to a desired object

Tags: r, get, load, r-s4

I have a vector like this :

```
vec1 <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
```

I have another vector like this :

```
vec2 <- c("X1.RData","X2.RData","X3.RData","X4.RData")
```

What I am trying to do here is to load the RData files and then save them back with the same file names but the objects should be that of the vec1.

```
for (i in 1:length(vec1)){
vec1[i] <- get(load(vec2[i]))
save(vec1[i],file=vec2[i])
}
```

but its giving me error saying `"incompatible types"`
I also tried changing the class of the character objects like this :

```
class(vec1[i]) <- myclass
```

where myclass is class of the S4 type object.

Is there a way to do this in R ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to know the names of the objects in each of the .Rdata files. Object names are saved with the object contents and when accessed using `load` do not get assigned the names of the files in which they are stored. Furthermore, you would need to use `assign` in order to give those objects a new name. Assuming you had nothing else in the workspace at the time:

Untested:

```
for (i in 1:length(vec1)){ load(vec2[i])
   assign( vec1[i] , get( ls() )
   save(vec1[i],file=vec2[i])
   rm(list=ls(patt="^x.$") )
}
```

If you have other things in the workspace, then you really do need to know the names of the objects in those .Rdata files. (Although if you `load()`-ed these into an specific environment, you might be able to insulate the process from the rest of your workspace/)